# How can I compress images,so that google pagespeed test won't recommend to compress that image again?

Tags: image, image-processing, pagespeed, image-compression, google-pagespeed

Whenever I run pagespeed test , it gives possible optimization of images in bytes & percentage like,
  Compressing and resizing https://example.com/…ts/AMP.jpg?6750368613317441460 could save 530KiB (91% reduction).

Compressing https://example.com/…AMP.png?12287830358450898504 could save 4.4KiB (31% reduction).

I am using ImageMagick to compress the images.

I have tried  `convert AMP.gif_or_png -strip  [-alpha Remove] OUTPUT.png`  for png images  and

```
 convert INPUT.jpg -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -strip [-quality 85] [-interlace JPEG] [-colorspace RGB] OUTPUT.jpg
```

for jpg images, but none of the above commands gives me the same reduction as suggested by google pagespeed.
 So, let me know if i am missing any parameters or I have passed wrong values of parameters.

The pack of compressed contents are available on google pagespeed page but,I want to compress images using ImageMagick 
 or any other sources .

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a commercial tool, [JPEGmini](http://www.jpegmini.com/) can be used. You can also use [imagemin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-imagemin) if you are going to use Grunt task runner. You can also use command lines tools that are provided with imagemin such as [jpeg-tran](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/) and [opti-png](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/), and they are open source as well.

Answer (score 2):

May be, there is no tool available to do your task dynamically,You should do some calculations or if your doing your task with any language then there are many inbuilt classes are available so  you can use these classes to compress images, like in java Imagescalr, Thumbnail or ImageWriteParam or you can go with Matlab also.

Comment: So Are you sure I can compress images using java ?, because I m using java maven project.

Answer (score 1):

> Compressing and resizing https://example.com/…ts/AMP.jpg?6750368613317441460 could save 530KiB (91% reduction).

530 KiB reduction is quite a lot. Verify that the **image size** is congruous. I mean, if you have a 400x200 image and you show it at 200x100, then serving it at the correct resolution (or resolutions) could be what PageSpeed is after.

For PNG images, often color reduction is possible: if you have a 12 colors image (e.g. a schematic), having it in 24-bit, 8-bit or 4-bit format makes a significant difference, while changing nothing in what people see once it's displayed. Good call removing unneeded alpha channel, though.

The rest you can do with tools like `pngopt`, `pngcrush` or `advpng`. JPEG quality parameter or suitable tools ([tinyjpg](https://tinyjpg.com/), or google 'JPEG compression optimizer') can be used to improve JPEG size. There are some tools that are capable of selectively encoding different areas of the image, or rewrite a PNG palette to leverage zLib compression features.

Another possibility with JPEG is using the *progressive* format, that allows quickly displaying a raw image, and refine it iteratively. More overall bandwidth but also more *apparent* speed (less browser support also; check it out).

It is not automatic that any of this can be done with ImageMagick - after all, ImageMagick is not directly tasked with **file** manipulation but with **image** manipulation. It may well be that its file-compression functions are not as complete or as advanced as other tools'.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a compression pack from that page with your images and code optimized to their liking...it is pretty much the best image compression available.

Comment: The pack of compressed contents are available on google pagespeed page but,I want to do image compression using ImageMagick 
 code or any other sources .

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [thumbor.org](http://thumbor.org/). It's a open source imaging service which you can simply start using a docker container on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. It has some pretty nice features like smart cropping and face detection.

To start it, just create a elastic beanstalk environment with docker as predefined configuration. Then you provide a JSON-File with following content in the application version tab.

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "apsl/thumbor"
  },
 "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "8000"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can then configure thumbor with elastic beanstalk environment variables. For optimizing JPG you should add the jpegtran optimizer.

OPTIMIZERS=['thumbor.optimizers.jpegtran']

We use it at Storyblok.com to optimize the images and Google Pagespeed is happy with the result: https://www.storyblok.com/docs/Guides/how-to-resize-images